# Swift 3 "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" for image inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a sign up form inside a tableview and in that signup form a user can select a profile image.

How do I update the image in the tableview cell with the image selected?

How do I allow the cell. inside "func imagePickerController()" which is not inside the tableview?

[Click for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOJz4.png)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

if let orginalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

cell.profileImage.image = orginalImage

}

else { print ("error") }

picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: error seems more on what is cell.

Comment: make original image to global and pass this image in tabview cell. You can not make cell there

Comment: you need to use Tableview delegates You can't Access cell as you are doing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your cell file object in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** method.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {


        //cell file object
        let cell = tblView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)) as! ProfileTableViewCell //cell file object

        let imgTemp = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage// get image from imagePickerViewController
        cell.imgViewProfile.image = imgTemp
        cell.imgViewProfile.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgViewProfile.frame.size.width/2 // make image circle
        cell.imgViewProfile.layer.masksToBounds = true
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: I did but my reputation is below 15 so it says it won't display publicly.

Comment: Was having a similar issue and with some work this answer completely solved my problem.  Thanks @Jaydip

Answer (score 1):

Inside didfinishPickingMediaWithInfo reuse the cell which u need to add image and simply assign the picked image to the imageView inside cell.

Simple!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var orginalImage

 if  orginalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

tableView.reloadData()

}
```

// now you can use this image in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.profileImage.image = orginalImage
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must just
>
> 1. Add local variable to your controller.
> 2. Set to var image from image picker
> 3. Reload cell/table

**For example**

```
class ImageViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

      var image: UIImage?
      weak var table: UITableView!

      func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

            if let orginalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.image = orginalImage
      } else { print ("error") }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

            return cell
      }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let _cell = cell

            _cell.imageView.image = self.image
      }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make image variable in your AppDelegate Like

```
var globalImage = UIImage()
```

and where you are getting value send it to AppDelegate. make AppDelgate object like below

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

to pass value to app delegate variable

```
self.appDelegate.globalImage = "your image here"
```

and get your values wherever you want to fetch like below

in your case its in TableViewCell so under cellforRowAt

```
cell.profileImage.image = appDelegate.globalImage
```

values passed

Comment: Using app delegate to store an image which will only be used inside one viewController is unnecessary and an overkill. The OP would be better off creating a global variable inside the said viewController as mentioned in @Latif kumar's comment